# Is there any predefined metrics which is used to monitor connection limit of cloud SQL in GCP and set alert on connection limit

Tags: google-cloud-platform

cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/postgresql/num_backends I search this metrics i chatGPT and it show that it is used to measure connection limit of database.

but I cant understand this.? Can you please suggest me metrics or how to monitor and set alert on connection limit of SQL database in GCP

I want to set alert on database connection limit

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct way to determine this as far as I could tell

We created a log-based metric with this query

```
resource.type="cloudsql_database" AND textPayload =~ "remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"
```

An alternative option is to use the built-in metric
`cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/postgresql/num_backends` (swap `postgresql` for your database type) and programmatically build the alert policy based on the connection limit set in the database (but this will need to be rebuilt if you increase the number of connections later)